# derivatives of little o

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, asymptotics

I read in various forums that there can be no clear relationship between a function that is a little o of some other function and its derivative. It seems to me that at least in the case I'm working on such a relationship exists. I know $f(x)=o(x^{-1})$ and that $f(x)$ is continuously differentiable

$$ 0 = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{1/x} = \lim_{x \to \infty}- \frac{f'(x)}{(1/x)^2}$$

using L'Hopital's rule. What is wrong with this proof?

Comment: It looks like you're arguing $f(x)\in o(x^{-1})\implies f'(x)\in o(x^{-2})$, but $-x^{-2}\to0$ as $x\to\infty$. Consider $f(x)=x^{-1-\epsilon}\sin(x^2)$ for small $\epsilon>0$.

Comment: "What is wrong with your proof" is that you assume the existence of $\lim_{x \to \infty}- \frac{f'(x)}{(1/x)^2}.$

Comment: @J.G. thanks for the swift answer. I see your point. The example you suggest relies on the fact $f$ and $f'$ oscillate around zero. I forgot to mention that I know $f'(x)<0 , \ \forall x$. Do you think these restrictions allow me to make my point? Thanks again

Comment: You should edit that into your question. I also advise you to consider the contrapositive, for which you may benefit from [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#The_Hardy%E2%80%93Littlewood_definition) notation.